# Why is exif_read_data() not working after moving file to other server?

Tags: php, exif

I am attempting to move a program from one server to another and the same script will not work and I can't figure out why...The below is a scaled down version of my script that fails:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string=file_get_contents("../photos/report14/concreteCurb/baseCompaction1.jpeg");
$exif = exif_read_data("data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode($string));
print_r($exif);
?>
```

The server that works spits out a simple

```
Array ( [FileName] => Z [FileDateTime] => 0 [FileSize] => 137976 [FileType] => 2 [MimeType] => image/jpeg [SectionsFound] => COMMENT [COMPUTED] => Array ( [html] => width="773" height="1000" [Height] => 1000 [Width] => 773 [IsColor] => 1 ) [COMMENT] => Array ( [0] => CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), quality = 90 ) )
```

...but the one that doesn't throws...

```
Warning: exif_read_data(): Unable to open file in /nfs/c11/h01/mnt/208416/domains/s208416.gridserver.com/html/advantage/scripts/test.php on line 5
```

Both have EXIF Support enabled (both version 1.4).  PHP version on the old server is 5.3.5 whereas the new has 5.5.21, but I also tried it reverted back to 5.3.29 to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, but if you're running this on a CentOS box (might not be directly related to the linux distro) you should try adding the absolute path to the file to the path like this:

```
$string = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '../photos/report14/concreteCurb/baseCompaction1.jpeg');
```

This has solved similar problems for me in the past.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!  Unfortunately, not the issue this time - just for good measure, though - I went ahead and echo'd out the $string and split out the base64_encoded string on both servers and both are identical - its definitely that exif_read_data function that's screwing it up.

Comment: Two other things - 1. are your servers identical other than the PHP version? I don't see any reason in the manual that this method would have different behaviour between versions. 2. [the manual](http://php.net/en/exif-read-data) says that the first parameter is a filename, so could you try passing your file path straight into it?

Comment: HAHA - oh my...doing so much with BASE64 in this app that I didn't even consider that it didn't need to be BASE64 at that point - putting the filename like you mentioned works! exif_read_data("../photos/report14/concreteCurb/baseCompaction1.jpeg")

Comment: Although, the reason that I can't exif_read_data on the base64 on this server setup is still up in the air - but this does solve my problem! Thank you! Sometimes you cant see the forest through the trees. Geez.